# Numeric comparison during merge in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Dataframe `d1`:

```
x  y
4 10
6 20
7 30
```

Dataframe `d2`:

```
x   z
3 100
6 200
9 300
```

How do I merge `d1` and `d2` by `"x"` where `d1$x` should be matched against exact match or the next higher number in `d2$x`. Output should look like:

```
x   y    z
4  10  200 # (4 is matched against next higher value that is 6)
6  20  200 # (6 is matched against 6)
7  30  300 # (7 is matched against next higher value that is 9)
```

If `merge()` cannot do this, then is there any other way to do this? For loops are painfully slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=c(4,6,7), y=c(10,20,30))
d2 <- data.frame(x=c(3,6,9), z=c(100,200,300))
```

You basically wish to extend `d1` by a new column. So let's copy it.

```
d3 <- d1
```

Next I assume that `d2$x` is sorted nondecreasingly and that`max(d1$x) <= max(d2$x)`.

```
d3$z <- sapply(d1$x, function(x) d2$z[which(x <= d2$x)[1]])
```

Which reads: *for each `x` in `d1$x`, get the smallest value from `d2$x` which is not smaller than `x`*.

Under these assumptions, the above may also be written as (& should be a bit faster):

```
d3$z <- sapply(d1$x, function(x) d2$z[which.max(x <= d2$x)])
```

In result we get:

```
d3
##   x  y   z
## 1 4 10 200
## 2 6 20 200
## 3 7 30 300
```

**EDIT1**: Inspired by @MatthewLundberg's `cut`-based solution, here's another one using `findInterval`:

```
d3$z <- d2$z[findInterval(d1$x, d2$x+1)+1]
```

**EDIT2**: (Benchmark)

Exemplary data:

```
set.seed(123)
d1 <- data.frame(x=sort(sample(1:10000, 1000)), y=sort(sample(1:10000, 1000)))
d2 <- data.frame(x=sort(c(sample(1:10000, 999), 10000)), z=sort(sample(1:10000, 1000)))
```

Results:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
{d3 <- d1; d3$z <- d2$z[findInterval(d1$x, d2$x+1)+1] },
{d3 <- d1; d3$z <- sapply(d1$x, function(x) d2$z[which(x <= d2$x)[1]]) },
{d3 <- d1; d3$z <- sapply(d1$x, function(x) d2$z[which.max(x <= d2$x)]) },
{d1$x2 <- d2$x[as.numeric(cut(d1$x, c(-Inf, d2$x, Inf)))]; merge(d1, d2, by.x='x2', by.y='x')},
{d1a <- d1; setkey(setDT(d1a), x); d2a <- d2; setkey(setDT(d2a), x); d2a[d1a, roll=-Inf] }
)
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr       min            lq    median        uq       max neval
## findInterval   221.102      1357.558  1394.246  1429.767  17810.55   100
## which        66311.738     70619.518 85170.175 87674.762 220613.09   100
## which.max    69832.069     73225.755 83347.842 89549.326 118266.20   100
## cut           8095.411      8347.841  8498.486  8798.226  25531.58   100
## data.table    1668.998      1774.442  1878.028  1954.583  17974.10   100
```

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straightforward using *rolling joins* with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)   ## >= 1.9.2
setkey(setDT(d1), x)  ## convert to data.table, set key for the column to join on 
setkey(setDT(d2), x)  ##  same as above

d2[d1, roll=-Inf]

#    x   z  y
# 1: 4 200 10
# 2: 6 200 20
# 3: 7 300 30
```

Answer (score 2):

`cut` can be used to find the appropriate matches in `d2$x` for the values in `d1$x`.

The computation to find the matches with `cut` is as follows:

```
as.numeric(cut(d1$x, c(-Inf, d2$x, Inf)))
## [1] 2 2 3
```

These are the values:

```
d2$x[as.numeric(cut(d1$x, c(-Inf, d2$x, Inf)))]
[1] 6 6 9
```

These can be added to `d1` and the merge performed:

```
d1$x2 <- d2$x[as.numeric(cut(d1$x, c(-Inf, d2$x, Inf)))]
merge(d1, d2, by.x='x2', by.y='x')
##   x2 x  y   z
## 1  6 4 10 200
## 2  6 6 20 200
## 3  9 7 30 300
```

The added column may then be removed, if desired.

Comment: +1 for `cut`. Also, `findInterval` will work similarly, I suppose.

Comment: @gagolews `findInterval` uses intervals that are closed on the left.  `cut` gives a choice (closed on the right is default).

Comment: @gagolews That effects only the last interval.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `sapply(d1$x,function(y) d2$z[d2$x > y][which.min(abs(y - d2$x[d2$x > y]))])`